# Opening shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-pro

I have the following files:
file.cpg, file.dbf, file.prf, file.sbn, file.sbx, file.shp, file.shp.xml, file.shx

How do I open this in ArcGIS Pro which is looking for a file with extension .aprx or .ppkx
or ArcMap which is looking for .mxd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file are not a "project" but just some data in shapefile format (all these file with the same name but different extension are what is called a shapefile, for more information on what the different file are see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile))

So if you want to visualise these file you will need to use the "[add data](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/adding-layers-to-a-map.htm)" way rather than the "open a project" way (be aware that these data will display without any symbology but a default random color symbol)